# How do I filter marks greater than or equal to 90 in this array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, arraylist, filter

```
let students = [
  {"Name": "Priya","marks": [50, 60, 70, 80, 90]},
  {"Name": "Ankita","marks": [80, 90, 95]}
]
```

Result should be this,

```
[{"Name": "Priya", "marks": [90]}, {"Name": "Ankita","marks": [90,95]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Nikhil's first answer will modify the original array, which is not advisable, so you can simply do this.**

```
let students = [
      {"Name": "Priya","marks": [50, 60, 70, 80, 90]},
      {"Name": "Ankita","marks": [80, 90, 95]}
    ]
```

**Now, I want to filter marks greater than or equal to 90, The code will look like this.**

```
students.map((student) => {
  return {...student, 
          marks: student.marks.filter((mark) => mark >= 90)
         }
}) 
// Result will be [{"Name": "Priya", "marks": [90]}, {"Name": "Ankita","marks": [90,95]}]
```

`Spread operator` will expand `student` and then it will override the `marks key` with `filtered marks value`.

If you do not use spread operator,

```
students.map((student) => student.marks.filter((mark) => mark >= 90))
// Result will be [[90],[90]]
```

Then you will get only the filtered values and not the values on which you haven't applied the filter.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter the values of an array based on a condition.

**Update existing array** (Use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach))

```js
let students = [{"Name": "Priya","marks": [50, 60, 70, 80, 90]},{"Name": "Ankita","marks": [80, 90, 95]}];

students.forEach(o => o.marks = o.marks.filter(v => v >= 90));
console.log(students);
```

**Create new array** (Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) & [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign))

```js
let students = [{"Name": "Priya","marks": [50, 60, 70, 80, 90]},{"Name": "Ankita","marks": [80, 90, 95]}];

let result = students.map(o => Object.assign({}, o, {marks : o.marks.filter(v => v >= 90)}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()`, `.filter()` and `Object.assign()` methods:

```js
let data = [
  {"Name": "Priya","marks": [50, 60, 70, 80, 90]},
  {"Name": "Ankita","marks": [80, 90, 95]}
];

let result = data.map(
  o => Object.assign(o, {marks: o.marks.filter(v => v >= 90)})
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```